# Python Read txt file from highest to lowest score

Tags: python, text

Complete beginner here, I am currently doing an exercise where I have to make Python read a text file with countries and scores and then I need to print the highest score first until the lowest score.
So for example a text file could look like the following:

`Canada 14
Brazil 9
South Korea 16`

(There are many other additional text files with different scores, but I start with the first one)
My code until now:

```
firstscoredocument = f.readlines()
for line in firstscoredocument:
    nums_str = line.split()[1:]
    nums = [int(n) for n in nums_str]
    max_in_line = max(nums)
    print max_in_line
```

This code prints 

`14
9
16`

I would need it to print

`South Korea 16
Canada 14
Brazil 9`

Also, I can't seem to find a way how to print them from highest to lowest...
Can anyone give me a hint please?
thank you very much :)

Comment: You should be using Python 3 (where you'd write `print(max_in_line)`), Python 2 will be [end-of-life'd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#End-of-life) next month.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to Say this !!! but don't use the Stack overflow to complete your homework problems. This will impact your [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) in the forum.

Here [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) will help you in this, assume that you're using a [tab delimited file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values#Example).

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("sample_file.txt",sep='\t',header=None)
sort_by_life = data.sort_values(by=data.columns[1],ascending=False)
sort_by_life.to_csv("sort_by_life.txt", sep='\t', index=False, header=None)
print(sort_by_life)
```

**Output:**

```
South Korea 16
Canada  14
Brazil  9
```

Try to use Python 3, since [python 2.x will be end of life.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/#maintenance-releases)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file into a dictionary then [sort the dictionary by values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177911/3064538) and print it out:

```
with open("filename.txt") as f:
    countries_to_scores = {}
    for line in f:
        country, score = line.strip().split()
        countries_to_scores[country] = score

for country in sorted(countries_to_scores, key=countries_to_scores.get):
    print(country, counties_to_scores[country])
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import os

with open(r'yourtextfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    firstscoredocument = [x.replace('\n', '') for x in f.readlines() if x != '\n']
    country_and_scores = []
    for line in firstscoredocument:
        if line == os.linesep:
            continue
        c, s = line.rsplit(' ', 1)
        country_and_scores.append([c, int(s)])

    country_and_scores.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) 
    for country_score in country_and_scores:
        print(*country_score )
```

Comment: there's no point to use `readlines` and checking for `os.linesep`, you can just do `for line in f` and then `if not line.strip(): continue`. Python automatically converts newlines to `\n` on all operating systems.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you read the values into a dictionary, then sort that by values. If you manage to create dictionary x in the example below, you will then be able to sort it and print it.

```
import operator
x = {"South Korea": 16, "Brazil": 9, "Canada": 14}
sorted_x = sorted(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
print(sorted_x)
[('South Korea', 16), ('Canada', 14), ('Brazil', 9)]
```

Comment: It will work if he is able to make a dictionary {"country": score} from the input file.